# Passing a function to another function in C++ where the number of arguments can be different

Tags: c++, c++17, decorator

I am working on a problem in C++17 where I am building a root solver that allows the user to pass a user-defined function to the root-solving function.  An example of the class is shown below for the `.cpp` file and the prototype is in the `.hpp` file.

```
// root.cpp
double RootSolver::newton(double guess, double right_side,
                          double (*func)(double),
                          double unc, int iter)
/**
Finds a specific root of a function using the Newton iteration
method

 @param guess      An initial guess for the value of the root
 @param right_side The value of the right side of the
                   function.
 @param func       The function for which the root will be
                   determined
 @param unc        The uncertainty or tolerance in the accepted
                   solution.  Defaulted to 0.001
 @param iter       The number of iterations to try before the
                   function fails.  Defaulted to 150.
 @return root
 */
{
    double x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, slope;
    x1 = guess;
    x2 = x1 + 0.0000001;
    for (int i = 0; i < iter; i++)
    {
        y1 = func(x1) - right_side;
        y2 = func(x2) - right_side;
        slope = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
        x3 = x1 - (y1 / slope);
        if (func(x3) - right_side <= unc and
            func(x3) - right_side >= -unc) return x3;
        x1 = x3;
        x2 = x1 + 0.0000001;
    }
    exit_program(iter);
}
// ================================================================
// RootSolver PRIVATE FUNCTIONS

[[noreturn]] void RootSolver::exit_program(int iter)
{
    std::string one("Function did not converge within ");
    std::string two(" iterations");
    std::cout << one << iter << two << std::endl;
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

The main file looks like this;

```
double func1(double x);
double func2(double x, double a, double b);
int main() {
    RootSolver q;
    double guess = 2.0;
    double right_side = 0.0;
    // This function works fine
    result = q.newton(guess, right_side, func1)

    // - Not sure how to reformat RootSolver.newton so
         I can pass it func1 as well as func2 so it can
         accept the arguments a and b
    return 0;
}

double func1(double x)
{
    return pow(x, 6) - x - 1.0;
}

double func2(double x)
{
    return pow(x, 6) - a * x - b * 1.0;
}
```

The code shown above works great for func1, since `x` is the only argument; however, I am not sure how to reformat the `RootSolver.newton` function so it will take `func1` with no arguments except `x` and accept `func2` and the arguments `a` and `b`.  Does anyone know how I can pass arguments to the function `newton` such that it is not hardcoded for a specific input function?

Comment: How do you intend to call this function? Will you only pass 1 or 3 arguments?

Comment: @JVApen, there in lies the issue.  I am trying to write generic function that allows you to pass a user defined number of variables.  In one case maybe it is just one, in another case maybe three.

Comment: Sounds like you want some template magic. I'm just not sure what you want to achieve: have an upper bound of arguments to pass? Pass default values? Or simply accept a vector iso separate arguments.

Comment: Are the arg always doubles? Probably the most efficient approach would be to pass a pointer to an array and the length of the array. Passing a vector ref would be cleaner but you have the overhead of the vector heap if it's changing often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the loose description, it sounds like a caller-side lambda solves your problem:

```
result = q.newton(guess, right_side, [](double x) {
    return func2(x, 0, 0); // Replace 0s with values of a and b.
});
```

This lambda is converted to `double(*)(double)` as needed. Note that this will not work if you need to capture something because function pointers can't store additional state. There are two easy ways to handle that.

1. Make a template (and put the definition in the header):

   ```
   template<typename F>
     // requires std::is_invocable_r_v<double, F, double> // C++20 constraint option A
     // requires requires(F f, double x) { f(x) -> double; } // C++20 constraint option B - can be extracted into a concept
   double RootSolver::newton(double guess, double right_side,
                             F func,
                             double unc, int iter)
   ```
2. Use `std::function` at the cost of some performance when calling it:

   ```
   double RootSolver::newton(double guess, double right_side,
                             const std::function<double(double)>& func,
                             double unc, int iter)
   ```

Comment: I had to do some research on `std::function` before I could implement this, but it seems that option 2 solves my problem.  However, for the purpose of learning, can you describe what std::is_invocable_r_v and requires do?

Comment: @Jon, `is_invocable_r_v<R, F, Args>` checks whether calling an instance of `F` with `Args` returns something convertible to `R`. `F` matches the actual type passed in. In this case, the type of a lambda, which is equivalent to writing out your own class with a function call operator. `requires` is an easy way in C++20 to explicitly require something of a template argument up front instead of just going with the overload and giving the user a cryptic error inside the function body if a wrong type is passed. Since `func` is being called a specific way, it's good practice to state that up front.

Answer (score 2):

You can use function overloading in this case.

You can pass function name and x, a and b as parameters in overloaded versions, somewhat like this (I am just considering func, x, a and b for now, but you get the idea):

1) Overloaded version 1 that accepts func1 and its 2-parameters

```
double newton(...<other parameters>..., double (*func)(double), double x)
```

2) Overloaded version 2 that accepts func2 and its 3-parameters

```
double newton(...<other parameters>..., double (*func)(double, double, double), double x, double a, double b)
```

Now when you wish to call with func1, use:

```
newton(...., func1, x)
```

when you wish to call with func2, use:

```
newton(..., func2, x, a, b)
```